# How do I grep many files for many strings?

Tags: grep, search

I have a file with many strings. For simplicity, assume it is newline-delimited, and that each string is made up of only contain alphanumeric ASCII characters and underscore.

Now, I want to search a file / multiple files for occurrences of any of these strings. If there are not very many of them, I suppose I could just concatenate them with `|` and use a single grep. But - what if there are thousands, or tens of thousands, of them?

Comment: `grep -f file_with_patterns files*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your file with many strings, one per line, as an argument to `grep`’s `-f` option, which tells it to look for strings listed in the named file:

```
grep -f patterns.txt *
```

(or whatever glob is appropriate). `grep` will find any line in the given files which match any of the patterns in `patterns.txt`.

You probably should specify `-F` too if all the strings are fixed strings to match.